# QT C++ Creating grid with function for selecting multiple gridpoints

Tags: c++, qt, visualization

for my university I am working on a project, where I need to create a plate which shows the changes of the temperature in comparison to the time. Therefore I used QT DataVisualization to show how it changes. Actually I only need a 2D Visualization for it and not a 3D Visualization? Ist it possible to create a 2D visualization with the QT DataVisualization as well? Right know, the height shows how warm the plate is, if the point is low, it is cold, if the gridpoint is high, the plate is hot.

The next thing I want to do is to create a tool, for selecting multiple grid points on the Visualization. I've read something about QTRubberBand, but does it work in the same framework? Do you have any better Idea, which framework I should use for it?

It has to be possible to upgrade the visualization when the Slider is moved.

Do you have any ideas how I can do it with the QDataVisualization tool?

Here you can see a picture, how it looks right now:

[Visualization of the plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw396.png)

Thanks in advance!

Blacktiger800

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand correctly you just need a 2D graph with the ability to select the points?

```
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
// Fill it up with your data
Chart *chart = new Chart();
chart->addSeries(series);
```

Then to deal with the selection, you can override QChartView for the mouse event handlers. It might actually be chart you're subclassing, not sure on this.

```
class ChartView : public QChartView
```

Then you can override mouse event handlers.

```
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

Then take the line series data, iterate through it and get all the points that lie within the bounding box you've created (you can create this yourself just using the mouse events, or do it with a QRubberBand if you want to render it). Something like this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrubberband.html

```
void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    origin = event->pos();
    if (!rubberBand)
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize()));
    rubberBand->show();
}

void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, event->pos()).normalized());
}

void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->hide();
    // determine selection, for example using QRect::intersects()
    // and QRect::contains().
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to color the visualization just as shown on the picture? 

If I am using the rubberband, how do I know, which points are selected and which are not selected?